# how to call an event from a form using a control (button, for example)?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, events

Is it possible? I need to call the `Form1_FormClosing` here:

```
ContextMenu trayMenu = new ContextMenu();
trayMenu.MenuItems.Add("Close", delegate {
    Form1_FormClosing(????)
});
```

I need it because I'm using the CancelEventArgs from _FormClosing event:

```
private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    if (th != null && th.ThreadState == System.Threading.ThreadState.Running)
    {
        if (MessageBox.Show("the process is running, you want stop it?", "app", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel) == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            AbortProccess();                     }
        else
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
        }
    }
}
```

I hope this is clear,thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few things you could do.
First, you could just close the form using `myForm.Close()` as this will indirectly call the `FormClosing` event. Also, you could move everything within the `FormClosing` event into a separate method instead of in the event itself. You can then call that method from the event and from your MenuItem. If you don't want to do either of those, you could try using this as the delegate:

```
//CancelEventArgs can also take a boolean which dictates if 
//it should be cancelled
Form1_FormClosing(this, new CancelEventArgs());
```

Comment: Form1.Close() is rather horrible vb.net syntax.  Form1 is a class, not an object.  In C# that method would have to be static.  It is not.

Comment: Good points. I've changed the code to show that the instance's Close method should be called.

Comment: use `this` instead `Form1` as @HansPassant mentioned.

Comment: Forgot to change that when I changed the `Close` method.

Answer (score 3):

```
ContextMenu trayMenu = new ContextMenu();
trayMenu.MenuItems.Add("Close", delegate {
     this.Close();
});
```

Comment: Not sure if there is any issue. I usually keep myself far from C# and .NET, however it is basically what Hans suggested above; calling Close on the object is straight forward.

Comment: @fabianhjr: it's possible that it's because I accidentally used "Form1" instead of "this". A reason for the downvote would have pointed that out to me, and I would have fixed that sooner.

Comment: Well, yes I came after that edit. By 45 seconds actually, I noticed that. Well, it is a shame. Hope he comes back and realizes his mistake.

Comment: I don't know. Maybe because this it is "horrible vb.net syntax" for some.

Comment: @Kakashi: what is horrible vb.net syntax?

Answer (score 3):

This is technically possible, just call the OnFormClosing() method.  But that doesn't actually close the form, it should only ever run when the form actually closes.  Pretending that the form is closing when it is not actually closing is going to lead to disappointment.

So just call the Close() method instead.